# Combinations of countries with infinite and finite boundaries

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Hudson outlines that for separation of the plane into $n$ contiguous coloured regions of finite interior but infinite boundary so that no two colours touch one requires $n$ colours in his article "Four Colors Do Not Suffice" 2003.

On the other hand the famous four colour theorem states that for separation of the plane into arbitrary contiguous coloured regions of finite interior and finite boundary a maximum of four colours is required.

What is the minimum number of colour required for an arbitrary map of $n$ countries with $a$ countries with finite interior and infinite boundary and $b$ countries with finite interior and finite boundary such that $a + b = n$?

Comment: The article is available on-line through JSTOR, see [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3647828?seq=1).  Note that the maps considered there allow for a finite length "slit" of missing points in the plane, so that the discussion of what "maps" you are willing to consider needs clarification.

Comment: We could add the missing points to any of the regions and still have those regions be connected (but not path-connected) so maybe that's the specific kind of region that's problematic